# Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error with the following statement within in my code, i have went through it and i cant see anything wrong unless i have missed something:

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword RIGHT"

```sql
("SELECT D1.DR, D1.CR, D1.ASSET_NO, (Coalesce(addit_ytd,0) + DR - CR) AS ADDIT_YTD"
+"FROM (SELECT coalesce (sum(dr_amount),0) AS DR, coalesce (sum(cr_amount),0) AS CR , asset.asset_no" 
+"FROM posting RIGHT JOIN asset ON asset.asset_no = posting.asset_no, sysasset" 
+"WHERE asset.asset_no = @AssetNumber" 
+"AND (period <= posting.period) AND (period >= sysasset.asset_open_per)" 
+ "GROUP BY asset.asset_no) AS D1 INNER JOIN dbo.asset ON D1.asset_no= asset.asset_no", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

Comment: At least you should format it as sql. then maybe you will find the error yourself.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Consider a literal string: `@"..."`. It can go over multiple lines. So you won't have to concatenate so much. Downside is that any indentation is considered part of the string.

Comment: @Peri I formatted it as `SQL` instead. I don't think it helps much..

Comment: No you did not. It is a string that is concatenated!

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, you are missing whitespace. Consider rewriting your code to use C#'s *verbatim literal string* syntax, and maybe add some indentation in there to indicate the structure of the query better:

```
(@"SELECT D1.DR, D1.CR, D1.ASSET_NO, (Coalesce(addit_ytd,0) + DR - CR) AS ADDIT_YTD
FROM 
    (SELECT coalesce (sum(dr_amount),0) AS DR, coalesce (sum(cr_amount),0) AS CR ,     asset.asset_no
    FROM posting RIGHT JOIN asset ON asset.asset_no = posting.asset_no, sysasset
    WHERE asset.asset_no = @AssetNumber
    AND (period <= posting.period) AND (period >= sysasset.asset_open_per)
    GROUP BY asset.asset_no) 
AS D1 INNER JOIN dbo.asset ON D1.asset_no= asset.asset_no",         
DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

See, the @ sign means "take the string directly out of the source code". All the whitespace in the source code becomes whitespace in the string.

Answer (score 2):

The error is during the concatenation if the string. You need to have extra space after a column or before the `FROM` clause,

```
("SELECT D1.DR, D1.CR, D1.ASSET_NO, (Coalesce(addit_ytd,0) + DR - CR) AS ADDIT_YTD" +
" FROM (SELECT coalesce (sum(dr_amount),0) AS DR, coalesce (sum(cr_amount),0) AS CR , asset.asset_no" +
" FROM posting RIGHT JOIN asset ON asset.asset_no = posting.asset_no, sysasset" +
" WHERE asset.asset_no = @AssetNumber" +
" AND (period <= posting.period) AND (period >= sysasset.asset_open_per)" + 
" GROUP BY asset.asset_no) AS D1 INNER JOIN dbo.asset ON D1.asset_no= asset.asset_no", DataAccess.AssetConnection); 
 ^ << for clarity add extra space here
```

if you don't add extra space, the select statement will be parse into

```
... (Coalesce(addit_ytd,0) + DR - CR) AS ADDIT_YTDFROM (SELECT coalesce
                                                  ^ causes syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing whitespace characters between each line:

```
... ADDIT_YTD" +
"FROM ( ...
```

becomes

```
... ADDIT_YTDFROM ( ...
```

etc.

Just because you have newlines in your source, doesn't mean those newlines appear in your constructed text. (On a side note, I'm quite impressed with how far it gets (down into the middle of the 3rd line, apparently) before it's not a syntactically correct piece of SQL)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other answers I'll point out that normally when I have any SQL that is going in to production code I normally include it as a resource and refer to the text that way rather than having it hard coded inside the c# code. This lets you reuse the SQL code multiple places and also makes it easier to read the SQL code when you do need to edit it.